# Hide symlink destination in ls-lisp output?

Tags: dired, symbolic-links

By default Emacs' [ls-lisp](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/ls-lisp.el) shows the symlink destination in its output like this:

```
/tmp:
total used in directory 2 available 12933091
lrwxr-xr-x  40 02-07 16:12 foo -> bar
-rw-r--r--   0 03-06 14:45 bar
```

Is there any way to make ls-lisp not show the symlink destination (the "-> bar" part)?

The reason for asking this is that the symlink destination can in some cases be very long and cause a linebreak, which looks ugly in dired.

Answer (score 3):

Dunno whether there is something specific to `ls-lisp` (haven't found it), but for Dired more generally, if you turn on `dired-hide-details-mode` (e.g., using **`(`**), and if you the value of option **`dired-hide-details-hide-symlink-targets`** is non-nil then the targets of symlinks are hidden when details are hidden.

(If the length of the target name is a problem you can also consider using relative symbolic links, which are typically much shorter.  Command `dired-do-relsymlink` (bound to `Y`) from `dired-x.el` creates a relative symlink.)

Answer (score 0):

> The reason for asking this is that the symlink destination can in some cases be very long and cause a linebreak, which looks ugly in dired.

An alternative approach would be to enable line truncation for dired buffers:

```el
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'my-dired-mode-hook)

(defun my-dired-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `dired-mode' behaviours."
  (setq truncate-lines t))
```

I do recommend using `dired-hide-details-mode` as mentioned by Drew, but truncating lines might be preferable to entirely hiding symlink targets.

`<C-next>` and `<C-prior>` (n.b. next/prior are typically Page Down and Page up keys) are used to scroll horizontally when lines are truncated.